# How to check WiFi connection using intentfilter and broadCastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How to check the if there is there is wifi connection currently established or not using BroadCastReceiver?

I tried some examples but i do not which intentFilter should i use for that?

please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

menifest file:-

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.ideal.log.activitymaster.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Receiver

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

            String status = getConnectivityStatusString(context);

            Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
            int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
            String status = null;
            if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
                status = "Wifi enabled";
            } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                status = "Mobile data enabled";
            } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                status = "Not connected to Internet";
            }
            return status;
        }
public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
    }
```

I hope it will helps.

**----UPDATE-----**
it is also possible to register receiver programatically.
**registering**

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));

NetworkChangeReceiver receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
```

**Un Registerger**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: ok, but how to reister the receiver programatically? is it pssible?